# Routing Cannot read property length of undefined

Tags: angular, routes

I run into the following error when navigating to any route. (Thats why I think it has to do with routing but thats just a guess...)

```
VM8792:48 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in ./ContactComponent class ContactComponent_Host - inline template:0:0 caused by: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at SafeSubscriber.eval [as _next] (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/app.js:1674:1), <anonymous>:42:56)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:29:1), <anonymous>:223:16)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:29:1), <anonymous>:172:22)
    at Subscriber._next (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:29:1), <anonymous>:125:26)
    at Subscriber.next (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:29:1), <anonymous>:89:18)
    at RefCountSubscriber.Subscriber._next (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:29:1), <anonymous>:125:26)
    at RefCountSubscriber.Subscriber.next (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:29:1), <anonymous>:89:18)
    at Subject.next (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:44:1), <anonymous>:55:25)
    at ConnectableSubscriber.Subscriber._next (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:29:1), <anonymous>:125:26)
    at ConnectableSubscriber.Subscriber.next (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:29:1), <anonymous>:89:18)
    at TextcontentService.load (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/app.js:38:1), <anonymous>:161:35)
    at ContactComponent.ngOnInit (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/app.js:1653:1), <anonymous>:25:33)
    at Wrapper_ContactComponent.detectChangesInInputProps (/AppModule/ContactComponent/wrapper.ngfactory.js:18:53)
    at _View_ContactComponent_Host0.detectChangesInternal (/AppModule/ContactComponent/host.ngfactory.js:30:30)
    at _View_ContactComponent_Host0.AppView.detectChanges (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:3472:1), <anonymous>:233:14)
    at _View_ContactComponent_Host0.DebugAppView.detectChanges (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:3472:1), <anonymous>:338:44)
    at ViewRef_.detectChanges (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:2508:1), <anonymous>:136:20)
    at RouterOutlet.activate (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:2708:1), <anonymous>:100:42)
    at ActivateRoutes.placeComponentIntoOutlet (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:550:1), <anonymous>:802:16)
    at ActivateRoutes.activateRoutes (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:550:1), <anonymous>:780:22)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:550:1), <anonymous>:749:19)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at ActivateRoutes.activateChildRoutes (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:550:1), <anonymous>:748:29)
    at ActivateRoutes.activate (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:550:1), <anonymous>:743:14)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:550:1), <anonymous>:493:56)
    at SafeSubscriber.eval [as _next] (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:108:21)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrSetError (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:29:1), <anonymous>:232:16)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:29:1), <anonymous>:174:27)
    at Subscriber._next (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:29:1), <anonymous>:125:26)
    at Subscriber.next (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:29:1), <anonymous>:89:18)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:456:1), <anonymous>:133:30)
    at InnerSubscriber._next (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:4368:1), <anonymous>:23:21)
    at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.next (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:29:1), <anonymous>:89:18)
    at MapSubscriber._next (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:396:1), <anonymous>:83:26)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:29:1), <anonymous>:89:18)
    at ReduceSubscriber._complete (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:829:1), <anonymous>:105:30)
    at ReduceSubscriber.Subscriber.complete (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:29:1), <anonymous>:114:18)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._complete (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:456:1), <anonymous>:125:30)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.complete (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:29:1), <anonymous>:114:18)
    at ArrayObservable._subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:303:1), <anonymous>:116:24)
    at ArrayObservable.Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:56:27)
    at Observable._subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:114:28)
    at MergeMapOperator.call (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:456:1), <anonymous>:75:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:53:22)
    at Observable._subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:114:28)
    at ReduceOperator.call (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:829:1), <anonymous>:63:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:53:22)
    at Observable._subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:114:28)
    at MapOperator.call (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:396:1), <anonymous>:54:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:53:22)
    at Object.subscribeToResult (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:59:1), <anonymous>:21:27)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:456:1), <anonymous>:120:38)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:456:1), <anonymous>:117:14)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._next (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:456:1), <anonymous>:100:18)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:29:1), <anonymous>:89:18)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:456:1), <anonymous>:133:30)
    at InnerSubscriber._next (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:4368:1), <anonymous>:23:21)
    at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.next (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:29:1), <anonymous>:89:18)
    at EverySubscriber.notifyComplete (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:2037:1), <anonymous>:47:26)
    at EverySubscriber._complete (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:2037:1), <anonymous>:64:14)
    at EverySubscriber.Subscriber.complete (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:29:1), <anonymous>:114:18)
    at MergeAllSubscriber._complete (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:403:1), <anonymous>:94:30)
    at MergeAllSubscriber.Subscriber.complete (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:29:1), <anonymous>:114:18)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._complete (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:29:1), <anonymous>:132:26)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.complete (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:29:1), <anonymous>:114:18)
    at ArrayObservable._subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:303:1), <anonymous>:116:24)
    at ArrayObservable.Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:56:27)
    at Observable._subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:114:28)
    at MapOperator.call (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:396:1), <anonymous>:54:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:53:22)
    at Observable._subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:114:28)
    at MergeAllOperator.call (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:403:1), <anonymous>:63:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:53:22)
    at Observable._subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:114:28)
    at EveryOperator.call (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:2037:1), <anonymous>:27:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:53:22)
    at Object.subscribeToResult (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:59:1), <anonymous>:21:27)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:456:1), <anonymous>:120:38)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:456:1), <anonymous>:117:14)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._next (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:456:1), <anonymous>:100:18)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:29:1), <anonymous>:89:18)
    at MapSubscriber._next (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:396:1), <anonymous>:83:26)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:29:1), <anonymous>:89:18)
    at MapSubscriber._next (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:396:1), <anonymous>:83:26)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:29:1), <anonymous>:89:18)
    at MapSubscriber._next (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:396:1), <anonymous>:83:26)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:29:1), <anonymous>:89:18)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:456:1), <anonymous>:133:30)
    at InnerSubscriber._next (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:4368:1), <anonymous>:23:21)
    at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.next (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:29:1), <anonymous>:89:18)
    at Object.subscribeToResult (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:59:1), <anonymous>:16:25)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:456:1), <anonymous>:120:38)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:456:1), <anonymous>:117:14)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._next (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:456:1), <anonymous>:100:18)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:29:1), <anonymous>:89:18)
    at CatchSubscriber.Subscriber._next (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:29:1), <anonymous>:125:26)
    at CatchSubscriber.Subscriber.next (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:29:1), <anonymous>:89:18)
    at MapSubscriber._next (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:396:1), <anonymous>:83:26)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:29:1), <anonymous>:89:18)
    at MapSubscriber._next (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:396:1), <anonymous>:83:26)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:29:1), <anonymous>:89:18)
    at MapSubscriber._next (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:396:1), <anonymous>:83:26)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:29:1), <anonymous>:89:18)
    at LastSubscriber._complete (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:2881:1), <anonymous>:109:25)
    at LastSubscriber.Subscriber.complete (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:29:1), <anonymous>:114:18)
    at MergeAllSubscriber._complete (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:403:1), <anonymous>:94:30)
    at MergeAllSubscriber.Subscriber.complete (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:29:1), <anonymous>:114:18)
    at ScalarObservable._subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:1995:1), <anonymous>:51:28)
    at ScalarObservable.Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:56:27)
    at Observable._subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:114:28)
    at MergeAllOperator.call (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:403:1), <anonymous>:63:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:53:22)
    at Observable._subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:114:28)
    at LastOperator.call (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:2881:1), <anonymous>:38:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:53:22)
    at Observable._subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:114:28)
    at MapOperator.call (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:396:1), <anonymous>:54:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:53:22)
    at Observable._subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:114:28)
    at MapOperator.call (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:396:1), <anonymous>:54:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:53:22)
    at Observable._subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:114:28)
    at MapOperator.call (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:396:1), <anonymous>:54:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:53:22)
    at Observable._subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:114:28)
    at CatchOperator.call (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:2002:1), <anonymous>:30:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:53:22)
    at Observable._subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:114:28)
    at MergeMapOperator.call (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:456:1), <anonymous>:75:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:53:22)
    at Observable._subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:114:28)
    at MapOperator.call (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:396:1), <anonymous>:54:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:53:22)
    at Observable._subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:114:28)
    at MapOperator.call (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:396:1), <anonymous>:54:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:53:22)
    at Observable._subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:114:28)
    at MapOperator.call (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:396:1), <anonymous>:54:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:53:22)
    at Observable._subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:114:28)
    at MergeMapOperator.call (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:456:1), <anonymous>:75:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:53:22)
    at Observable._subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:114:28)
    at MergeMapOperator.call (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:456:1), <anonymous>:75:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:53:22)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:87:38)
    at new ZoneAwarePromise (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:3536:1), <anonymous>:518:29)
    at Observable.forEach (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:13:1), <anonymous>:86:16)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:550:1), <anonymous>:477:18)
    at new ZoneAwarePromise (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:3536:1), <anonymous>:518:29)
    at Router.runNavigate (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:550:1), <anonymous>:442:16)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:550:1), <anonymous>:433:67)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:3536:1), <anonymous>:232:26)
    at Object.onInvoke (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:1130:1), <anonymous>:238:37)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:3536:1), <anonymous>:231:32)
    at Zone.run (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:3536:1), <anonymous>:114:43)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:3536:1), <anonymous>:502:57)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:3536:1), <anonymous>:265:35)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:1130:1), <anonymous>:229:37)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:3536:1), <anonymous>:264:40)
    at Zone.runTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:3536:1), <anonymous>:154:47)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:3536:1), <anonymous>:401:35)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.ZoneTask.invoke (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:3536:1), <anonymous>:339:25)
```

Here are my versions:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/http": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "~3.1.1",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-alpha.8",
    "angular2-bootstrap-pagination": "^1.0.6",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.1.18",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-alpha.4",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "moment": "^2.14.1",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.1.14",
    "ng2-charts": "^1.4.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.25"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.14",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.4.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0-beta.4",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.5",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.3",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.15.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.4.1",
    "node-sass": "^3.8.0",
    "null-loader": "^0.1.1",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.7",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "ts-loader": "^0.8.1",
    "typescript": "^2.0.0",
    "typings": "^1.0.4",
    "webpack": "2.1.0-beta.22",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.1.0-beta.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^0.14.0"
  }
```

I am using this (in my module in providers array)

```
{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy},
```

and this is the way I am using the ROUTES (in my module in imports array):

```
RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES)
```

All my routes look similar to this one

```
 {
    path: 'contact',
    component: ContactComponent
  },
```

(some have an additional "canActivate" property)

This happens in both dev and prod mode.

Thanks for any help in advance!
Cheers, 
Raphael

EDIT:

Here is my ngOnInit of the ContactComponent as requested

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.textcontentService.textcontent.subscribe(latestText => {
      this.json = latestText;
    });
    this.textcontentService.load(Texttemplate.CONTACT);
}
```

It is pretty simple and just subscribing to a service and then loading specific data. I have this on almost every Component and it was never an issue before.

EDIT 2:

TextContentService is most definetly the trouble causer...

The idea of this service is to outsource text/content to json files and then inject them into the components via this service. So this service is just a Subject/Observable combo. It imports a bunch of json files and exports the service and ENUMS.

Then each component can load its text with the respective ENUM.

json import:

```
var contactTemplate = require('!json!./../../../../public/textcontent/contact/contact.json');
```

Subject/Observable

```
private _textcontentObserver: Subject<any> = new Subject();
public textcontent: Observable<any> = this._textcontentObserver.asObservable();
```

The load function is just a big switch case statement. Here the contact part:

```
case Texttemplate.CONTACT:
  this._textcontent = contactTemplate[this.language];
  break;
```

And then push the new content:

```
this._textcontentObserver.next(this._textcontent);
```

Okay why this EDIT 2: If I don't use this service at all I can navigate to the contact route without errors. But what is weird to me is that this service worked all the time and now its broken. Hope you guys can help me! :)

Comment: Can you show `ContactComponent.ngOnInit (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/app.js:1653:1), <anonymous>:25:33)`?

Comment: I've got the feeling the the textContentService might cause the troubles.. If I put all the content that is supposed to get delivered by textContentService into the component and just get rid of the ngOnInit and the Service completly it works...